# TypeError: db.getCollection is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to run aggregate function to get the count of files created till the given day. When I am running the query from the the terminal then it is working and when I am using it through the API I am getting error.

```
TypeError: db.getCollection is not a function
    at app.get (/Users/praveenkumarrana/Documents/Projects/Arema Technologies/Recorder Client/itsrecorder/routes/api/file.js:241:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/praveenkumarrana/Documents/Projects/Arema Technologies/Recorder Client/itsrecorder/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/praveenkumarrana/Documents/Projects/Arema Technologies/Recorder Client/itsrecorder/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at complete (/Users/praveenkumarrana/Documents/Projects/Arema Technologies/Recorder Client/itsrecorder/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:263:13)
    at /Users/praveenkumarrana/Documents/Projects/Arema Technologies/Recorder Client/itsrecorder/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:270:15
    at pass (/Users/praveenkumarrana/Documents/Projects/Arema Technologies/Recorder Client/itsrecorder/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:431:14)
    at Authenticator.transformAuthInfo (/Users/praveenkumarrana/Documents/Projects/Arema Technologies/Recorder Client/itsrecorder/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:453:5)
    at /Users/praveenkumarrana/Documents/Projects/Arema Technologies/Recorder Client/itsrecorder/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:267:22
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/Users/praveenkumarrana/Documents/Projects/Arema Technologies/Recorder Client/itsrecorder/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:55:13)
    at JwtStrategy.strategy.success (/Users/praveenkumarrana/Documents/Projects/Arema Technologies/Recorder Client/itsrecorder/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:248:13)
    at verified (/Users/praveenkumarrana/Documents/Projects/Arema Technologies/Recorder Client/itsrecorder/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:115:41)
    at User.findOne.then.user (/Users/praveenkumarrana/Documents/Projects/Arema Technologies/Recorder Client/itsrecorder/config/passport.js:17:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I have gone through many of the solution provide here but none answers my query. My app is created using create-react-app and backend is in nodeJs.

```
app.get(
    "/getcountdata",
    passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
    (req, res) => {

    db.getCollection('files').aggregate({$group:{_id:{$toDate: new Date(12-12-2019)}, count:{$sum:1}}})
        .then(files => {
        console.log(files);
        res.send({ files });
        })
        .catch(e => {
        res.status(400).send();
        });
    }
);
```

My expected result is to get data in the form of json like below.
{ "_id" : ISODate("1969-12-31T23:59:57.981Z"), "count" : 14 }

Thank You

Comment: how are you importing/instantiating `db`?

Comment: const db = require("../../config/keys").mongoURI;   - this is how I am importing the db.

Comment: Read the mongoose documentation on how to connect to a mongodb database. You are probably just passing a string and not an object/reference which knows how to connect to the db.